# Which admin user added product in magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2

I have store with 200 products and 6 user roles in backend who are allowed to enter products.

Is there any way that I could know that specific product is added by which user.

As I always go through he-did/she-did situation when something went wrong in product entry.

Comment: Here you can find my solution
[Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353791/103877)

Answer (score 3):

Magento does have this type feature on user/roles concept.

So you have to create a module custom module yourself.

And using `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` save 
 current admin username and product .

```
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after',
                ['controller' => $this, 'product' => $product]
            );
```

Comment: Is it for the products I'll add in future or I can see for the products that have been already added that which admin user added that product.

Comment: You have to save the post data   and current user detail on a customtable